# Get csv field values

Tags: arduino-uno

I am uploading data using Thingspeak and I would like to get only values stored in a field. Is there any way to get this in a cvs http request?

When you call a cvs http url, you get:

[image]

What I am trying to get is just the value in field2: 10,10,12,12,16 without the headers.

Comment: Is your hope to get just the content of field2 via the HTTP request? Or are you looking for a way to parse the data to get the content of the field?

Comment: I woud like to get just the content of field2 via HTTP request to integrate data into an array of chart library that only accepts thins kind of data.

Comment: Where you wrote, “i would like to get only values stored in a field.Is there any way to get this in a csv http request?.When you call a csv http url,you get: created_id,entry_id,field1,field2 2015-10-22 19:30:00,14878,18,5 ,what i am trying to get is only the value in field2: 5 without headers”, does  “csv” stand for **comma separated values** or is it some other acronym?  Please edit your question and make it more understandable.

Comment: The csv url data comes with comma separated values and all data is the first field when they opened with excel.I have edited the question and added a picture to show the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this format to achieve what you described:

```
http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/(channel_id)/field/(field_id).(format)
```

Source: http://community.thingspeak.com/documentation/api/

**Edit:** It seems that there are no available options that can do what you want. But, you can tweak the response like in this example:

```
  int i;
  String response = "created_at,entry_id,field2 2015-10-22 19:30:00,14878,5";

  for (i = response.length()-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
  {
    if (s.charAt(i) == ',') break;
  }
  String value = response.substring(i+1);
  Serial.println(value); // This will show only 5
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. I already tried that option through the following url:`https://thingspeak.com/channels/(channel_id)/fields/field2.csv?key=***&results=1` ,but the final result is:
`created_at,entry_id,field2
2015-10-22 19:30:00,14878,5`,so i don't know if there is more url options to get only 5 value.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems there are no options like that, but you can always try my answer.